# Not able to check json empty node

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
JsonNode jsonNode={"device": {},
  "customer_code": "a573aecc-03c6-472a-b2b9-4704ec9f3a92",
  "connector_list": "dz-connector-datadog",
  "configuration_id": "8cf91f32-7ce2-4111-9737-543d3ec787ae",
  "dz_app": "true",
  "video": {}
}
```

`jsonNode.get("device")` returns `{}`.I need to check whether device has values or not

Answer (score 0):

You can try this check:

```
jsonNode.size() == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for values by inspecting the size of the node:

```
if (jsonNode.get("device").size() == 0) {
    // Device object contains no values.
}
```